# How do I create persona for international airport website?

Tags: user-research

How do I create persona for international airport website?  How do I Identify my audience where audience base is diverse? And how many personas needed to be designed?

Comment: @JohnGB I agree that this question is very broad, but how can people new to the field get into it? I think we cannot expect newcomers to focus on a single item. And sure, there are books on persona creation, but probably not one focussing on airports ;-)

Comment: This wasn't closed because I don't like the question, but rather because it doesn't meet the requirements of questions on this site with this format.  Any reasonable answer to that question would be a small lecture series, and so doesn't suit this format.  People new to UX have many resources to go to, and if you want something as broad as this, then it's better to get a book dealing specifically with personas first. Then, if needed, you will have enough background to ask a narrow question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, "international airport website" is a little too vague. Are you targeting people flying from this airport?

Then it's easy - there should be plenty of people available for interviews at the airport: They have some experience with the airport (maybe even the website), they usually have some time (while waiting in a queue), and they probably have some opinion or story that they can share with you. So I'd spend a day doing some "pilot" study where I wander around the various places (drop-off, parking, check-in, shops, boarding, at least) and ask people about why they came here and what they want to do here. Be sure to interview outgoing (in the security queue or waiting to board) as well as incoming (at the luggage queue) people. Frequent hand-luggage-only people will be harder to interview, but there's usually some distance to walk; I'd try to accompany them.

The pilot should allow you to identify the most common groups related to travel: People bringing or picking up somebody else, first-flyers, business travellers, holiday travellers, together with some cross-sections like public transport vs. own car or just-flyers vs. heavy shoppers (maybe there even are shop-only visitors?). After you have these identified, you can tailor interview guides for these prototypes, do detailed interviews for each, and from these results, create personas.

I have no idea who else you might be interested in - job applicants, environmental groups, freight and transportation?

If you specifically need to target people who never visit(ed) the airport, I have no other idea than local newspapers/boards/etc.

Comment: Thanks virtualnobi! yes I mean people flying from this airport. And I was bit stumbled upon which audience to segment and who are the most important once to target and find commonalities. Your answer will surely helped me.

Comment: Harshal, glad I could help. If no better answer comes up, consider marking this as the best - feedback like that keeps us motivated.